# ANTLR island grammars and a non-greedy rule that consumes too much

Tags: c, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm having a problem with an island grammar and a non-greedy rule used to consume "everything except what I want".

**Desired outcome:**

My input file is a C header file, containing function declarations along with typedefs, structs, comments, and preprocessor definitions.
My desired output is parsing and subsequent transformation of function declarations ONLY. I would like to ignore everything else.

**Setup and what I've tried:**

The header file I'm attempting to lex and parse is very uniform and consistent.
Every function declaration is preceded by a linkage macro `PK_linkage_m` and all functions return the same type `PK_ERROR_code_t`, ex:

```
PK_linkage_m PK_ERROR_code_t PK_function(...);
```

These tokens don't appear anywhere other than at the start of a function declaration.

I have approached this as an island grammar, that is, function declarations in a sea of text.
I have tried to use the linkage token `PK_linkage_m` to indicate the end of the "TEXT" and the `PK_ERROR_code_t` token as the start of the function declaration.

**Observed problem:**

While lexing and parsing a single function declaration works, it fails when I have more than one function declaration in a file. The token stream shows that "everything + all function declarations + PK_ERROR_code_t of last function declaration " are consumed as text, and then only the *last* function declaration in the file is correctly parsed.

My one line summary is: My non-greedy grammar rule to consume everything before the `PK_ERROR_code_t` is consuming too much.

**What I perhaps incorrectly believe is the solution:**

Fix my lexer non-greedy rule somehow so that it consumes everything until it finds the `PK_linkage_m` token. My non-greedy rule appears to be consume too much.

**What I haven't tried:**

As this is my first ANTLR project, and my first language parsing project in a very long time, I'd be more than happy to rewrite it if I'm wrong and getting wronger. I was considering using line terminators to skip everything that doesnt start with newline, but I'm not sure how to make that work and not sure how it's fundamentally different.

**Here is my lexer file KernelLexer.g4:**

```
lexer grammar KernelLexer;
// lexer should ignore everything except function declarations
// parser should never see tokens that are irrelevant

@lexer::members {
    public static final int WHITESPACE = 1;
}

PK_ERROR: 'PK_ERROR_code_t' -> mode(FUNCTION);
PK_LINK: 'PK_linkage_m';

//Doesnt work. Once it starts consuming, it doesnt stop.
TEXT_SEA: .*? PK_LINK -> skip;

TEXT_WS: ( ' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t' ) -> skip;

mode FUNCTION;

//These constants must go above ID rule because we want these to match first.
CONST: 'const';
OPEN_BLOCK: '(';
CLOSE_BLOCK: ');' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
COMMA: ',';
STAR: '*';

COMMENTED_NAME: '/*' ID '*/';
COMMENT_RECEIVED: '/* received */' -> skip;
COMMENT_RETURNED: '/* returned */' -> skip;
COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;

ID : ID_LETTER (ID_LETTER | DIGIT)*;
fragment ID_LETTER: 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_';
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';

WS: ( ' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t' ) -> skip;//channel(1);
```

**Here is my parser file KernelParser.g4:**

```
parser grammar KernelParser;

options { tokenVocab=KernelLexer; }

file : func_decl+;

func_decl : PK_ERROR ID OPEN_BLOCK param_block CLOSE_BLOCK;

param_block: param_decl*;
param_decl: type_decl COMMENTED_NAME COMMA?;
type_decl: CONST? STAR* ID STAR* CONST?;
```

**Here is a simple example input file:**

```
/*some stuff*/

other stuff;

PK_linkage_m PK_ERROR_code_t PK_CLASS_ask_superclass
(
/* received */
PK_CLASS_t         /*class*/,             /* a class */
/* returned */
PK_CLASS_t *const  /*superclass*/         /* immediate superclass of class */
);

/*some stuff*/
blar blar;


PK_linkage_m PK_ERROR_code_t PK_CLASS_is_subclass
(
/* received */
PK_CLASS_t           /*may_be_subclass*/, /* a potential subclass */
PK_CLASS_t           /*class*/,           /* a class */
/* returned */
PK_LOGICAL_t *const  /*is_subclass*/      /* whether it was a subclass */
);


more stuff;
```

**Here is the token output:**

```
line 28:0 token recognition error at: 'more stuff;\r\n'
[@0,312:326='PK_ERROR_code_t',<'PK_ERROR_code_t'>,18:13]
[@1,328:347='PK_CLASS_is_subclass',<ID>,18:29]
[@2,350:350='(',<'('>,19:0]
[@3,369:378='PK_CLASS_t',<ID>,21:0]
[@4,390:408='/*may_be_subclass*/',<COMMENTED_NAME>,21:21]
[@5,409:409=',',<','>,21:40]
[@6,439:448='PK_CLASS_t',<ID>,22:0]
[@7,460:468='/*class*/',<COMMENTED_NAME>,22:21]
[@8,469:469=',',<','>,22:30]
[@9,512:523='PK_LOGICAL_t',<ID>,24:0]
[@10,525:525='*',<'*'>,24:13]
[@11,526:530='const',<'const'>,24:14]
[@12,533:547='/*is_subclass*/',<COMMENTED_NAME>,24:21]
[@13,587:588=');',<');'>,25:0]
[@14,608:607='<EOF>',<EOF>,29:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always difficult to cope with lexer rules "reading everything but ...", but you are on the right path.

After commenting out the skip action on `TEXT_SEA: .*? PK_LINK ; //-> skip;`, I have observed that the first function was consumed by a second `TEXT_SEA` (because lexer rules are greedy, `TEXT_SEA` gives no chance to `PK_ERROR` to be seen) :

```
$ grun Kernel file -tokens input.txt 
line 27:0 token recognition error at: 'more stuff;'
[@0,0:41='/*some stuff*/\n\nother stuff;\n\nPK_linkage_m',<TEXT_SEA>,1:0]
[@1,42:292=' PK_ERROR_code_t PK_CLASS_ask_superclass\n(\n/* received */\nPK_CLASS_t         
   /*class*/,    /* a class */\n/* returned */\nPK_CLASS_t *const  /*superclass*/
   /* immediate superclass of class */\n);\n\n/*some stuff*/\nblar blar;\n\n\n
   PK_linkage_m',<TEXT_SEA>,5:12]
[@2,294:308='PK_ERROR_code_t',<'PK_ERROR_code_t'>,17:13]
[@3,310:329='PK_CLASS_is_subclass',<ID>,17:29]
```

This gave me the idea to use `TEXT_SEA` both as "sea consumer" and starter of the function mode.

```
lexer grammar KernelLexer;
// lexer should ignore everything except function declarations
// parser should never see tokens that are irrelevant

@lexer::members {
    public static final int WHITESPACE = 1;
}

PK_LINK: 'PK_linkage_m' ;
TEXT_SEA: .*? PK_LINK  -> mode(FUNCTION);
LINE : .*? ( [\r\n] | EOF ) ;

mode FUNCTION;

//These constants must go above ID rule because we want these to match first.
CONST: 'const';
OPEN_BLOCK: '(';
CLOSE_BLOCK: ');' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
COMMA: ',';
STAR: '*';

PK_ERROR : 'PK_ERROR_code_t' ;
COMMENTED_NAME: '/*' ID '*/';
COMMENT_RECEIVED: '/* received */' -> skip;
COMMENT_RETURNED: '/* returned */' -> skip;
COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;

ID : ID_LETTER (ID_LETTER | DIGIT)*;
fragment ID_LETTER: 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_';
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

.

```
parser grammar KernelParser;

options { tokenVocab=KernelLexer; }

file : ( TEXT_SEA | func_decl | LINE )+;

func_decl
    :   PK_ERROR ID OPEN_BLOCK param_block CLOSE_BLOCK
            {System.out.println("---> Found declaration on line " + $start.getLine() + " `" + $text + "`");}
    ;

param_block: param_decl*;
param_decl: type_decl COMMENTED_NAME COMMA?;
type_decl: CONST? STAR* ID STAR* CONST?;
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Kernel file -tokens input.txt 
[@0,0:41='/*some stuff*/\n\nother stuff;\n\nPK_linkage_m',<TEXT_SEA>,1:0]
[@1,42:42=' ',<WS>,channel=1,5:12]
[@2,43:57='PK_ERROR_code_t',<'PK_ERROR_code_t'>,5:13]
[@3,58:58=' ',<WS>,channel=1,5:28]
[@4,59:81='PK_CLASS_ask_superclass',<ID>,5:29]
[@5,82:82='\n',<WS>,channel=1,5:52]
[@6,83:83='(',<'('>,6:0]
...
[@24,249:250=');',<');'>,11:0]
[@25,251:292='\n\n/*some stuff*/\nblar blar;\n\n\nPK_linkage_m',<TEXT_SEA>,11:2]
[@26,293:293=' ',<WS>,channel=1,17:12]
[@27,294:308='PK_ERROR_code_t',<'PK_ERROR_code_t'>,17:13]
[@28,309:309=' ',<WS>,channel=1,17:28]
[@29,310:329='PK_CLASS_is_subclass',<ID>,17:29]
[@30,330:330='\n',<WS>,channel=1,17:49]
[@31,331:331='(',<'('>,18:0]
...
[@55,562:563=');',<');'>,24:0]
[@56,564:564='\n',<LINE>,24:2]
[@57,565:565='\n',<LINE>,25:0]
[@58,566:566='\n',<LINE>,26:0]
[@59,567:577='more stuff;',<LINE>,27:0]
[@60,578:577='<EOF>',<EOF>,27:11]
---> Found declaration on line 5 `PK_ERROR_code_t PK_CLASS_ask_superclass
(

PK_CLASS_t         /*class*/,             

PK_CLASS_t *const  /*superclass*/         
);`
---> Found declaration on line 17 `PK_ERROR_code_t PK_CLASS_is_subclass
(

PK_CLASS_t           /*may_be_subclass*/, 
PK_CLASS_t           /*class*/,           

PK_LOGICAL_t *const  /*is_subclass*/      
);`
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this out locally and it works like a charm on the input file I provided. I will experiment with this a bit more as well as @BartKiers solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including `.*?` at the start of a rule (which I'd always try to avoid), why don't you try to match either:

- a `PK_ERROR` in the default mode (and switch to another mode like you're now doing),
- or else match a **single character and skip it**?

Something like this:

```
lexer grammar KernelLexer;

PK_ERROR : 'PK_ERROR_code_t' -> mode(FUNCTION);
OTHER    : . -> skip;

mode FUNCTION;

// the rest of your rules as you have them now
```

Note that this will match `PK_ERROR_code_t` as well for the input `"PK_ERROR_code_t_MU ..."`, so this would be a safer way:

```
lexer grammar KernelLexer;

PK_ERROR : 'PK_ERROR_code_t' -> mode(FUNCTION);
OTHER    : ( [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* | . ) -> skip;

mode FUNCTION;

// the rest of your rules as you have them now
```

Your parser grammar could then look like this:

```
parser grammar KernelParser;

options { tokenVocab=KernelLexer; }

file        : func_decl+ EOF;
func_decl   : PK_ERROR ID OPEN_BLOCK param_block CLOSE_BLOCK;
param_block : param_decl*;
param_decl  : type_decl COMMENTED_NAME COMMA?;
type_decl   : CONST? STAR* ID STAR* CONST?;
```

causing your example input to be parsed like this:

[image]

Comment: Neat ! Isn't there a drawback to emit thousands of one-character tokens ?

Comment: AFAIK, no real drawback.

Comment: @BartKiers Thank you for taking the time to work up a solution. I'm going to experiment with this approach and see if it works on more of my test cases (including the 10K+ lines of code I need to parse).